# PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat Error in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, psql

Script:

```
require 'pg'

con = PGconn.connect(:dbname => 'employee');
con.exec "SET datestyle TO DMY"

con.prepare 'getid' , "SELECT id FROM users WHERE user = $1 AND date IN ($2)"

str = "'21/07/2016' , '22/07/2016'"
res = con.exec_prepared 'getid' , ['usr1',str]
puts res.values
```

Output:

```
g.rb:10:in `exec_prepared': ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "'21/07/2016' , '22/07/2016'" (PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat) from g.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

My requirement is to get all the id's based on user name and date. But it gives the above error. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Pass an array of real date objects to PG, the driver will do the formatting job for you:

```
dates = %w|21/07/2016 22/07/2016|
res = con.exec_prepared 'getid', ['usr1', dates.map(&Date.method(:parse))]
```